# Wordpress Migration from one server to another(Pages not found)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I migrated the WordPress site from one server to another. Pages are not found, the error is coming while accessing the pages. I have updated the wp-config, .htaccess files and also changed the links and URL with the new site URL in the tables.

I have followed the below steps:

wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'my-db-name' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'my-db-user' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'my-db-pwd' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

WordPress Setting

```
    Settings->
    WordPress Address (URL) - New-URL
    Site Address (URL)      - New-URL
```

.htacess.php

```
    Generate the .htacess from Permalink Settings

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder-name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder-name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END Word

Database queries

```
    Updated tables wp_options , wp_posts , wp_usermeta, wp_links , wp_comments

    Example:

    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Existing URL', 'New URL');
```

The requested URL /New-URL/folder-name/page-name was not found on this server
    Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at New-URL Port 80

Comment: did you peek into permalink settings to refresh the permalink cache? https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/

Comment: Yes, I did flush the permalink settings and still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If permalinks are refreshed and you updated the database also, you probably have htaccess problems.

`.htaccess` should be spelled with double c, and should not have .php extension. You also have to update the `folder-name` inside to the actual folder you are using.

`.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /folder-name/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /folder-name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also check out this .htaccess file:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-i-without-url-change